# Schedule HTTP Request in Asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, httpcontext.cache

Every night my HTTPContext.Current.Cache is cleared. I want to *Warm up* the site during the night at time X and fill the cache with data.

Since I use HTTPContext, this has to run within the website. I am currently starting the caching by a simple button click on the site that then asynchronously fills the cache in a few minutes time frame.

I have searched for a solution where the options didn't really do the job as easily as I think it could be:

**System.Timers** are polling constantly. It also doesn't seem to have an option to set a specific time I want it to run?

**Quartz** seemed very overkill, but could probably do the job. Although a bit to read into to get it working.

**RegisterWaitForSingleObject** Could also work, but only a timer here as well? Also not sure if you can check if one object is already created and therefor risk of creating many of them. Nor change the timer after the object is created.

Skimmed through them relatively fast, so could be wrong. What's your take on running scheduled http request from within the site?

[EDIT] typo.

Comment: Is this application running on single instance or web farm/web garden?

Comment: task scheduler calling curl to request a page containing the relevant code?

Comment: @Win Running on Web farm.

Comment: @AlexK. Could perhaps work. Could you request the page with a button click on the site to start the code on-demand, without throwing the user to that page or in other way blocking them?

Comment: Just make the page do something when it loads, no need for interaction.

Comment: @AlexK. and that applies to the text I edited into my question? :) You were quick!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do-

1. Create a page within the site with anonymous access, and put the code to start the caching (which is written on button click right now) **ON THE PAGE LOAD event**.
2. Create a simple **console application** in C#, which makes HTTPRequest to that page (You can see examples for **System.Net.WebClient**).
3. Schedule the .exe of this console application to run at certain time  (like 4 AM) on Windows Scheduler on the server.

Comment: I'll try this out and see if I'll stick to it! Thanks.

Comment: This approach was very easy to setup and works. Still wants to know if there is another approach to it, since avoiding another project and config file would be great.

Comment: Happy to help, always! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted